# ANT read existing MANIFEST version and append to it

Tags: ant, build, manifest

I need to script an ant build which reads in the existing version from a META-INF/manifest.mf file and appends to it.

The updating should be possible using the ANT *manifest* task, however I've had trouble reading the existing version.

As the manifest entries are use *key*: *value* rather than *key*= *value* I cant read them in using ANT's *loadproperties* task.

Has anyone done this/ have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: loadproperties for key-colon-value works for me with Ant 1.8.1.

Comment: I can confirm it works with ant 1.7.1 also, my bad, a file check was preventing it from loading altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<manifest>` task should do exactly what you want. It will append new Manifest key=value pairs to an existing Manifest. Any idea why you can't use it?

You can use the `<concat>` task with the various filter readers, and then load the result with the `<loadproperties>` task. It takes a bit of elbow grease, but it might be a way to read in your *damaged* Manifest file this way, get the values, and then rewrite a new Manifest file with those old values.

I'd have to see a sample of your existing Manifest and what you want to add to it in order to figure out exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks David, running a simple test it was my check to see if the manifest file was available that was preventing the loadproperty from running so I assumed it didn't work. The loadproperty does work with the manifest and the manifest task works fine :)

Answer (score 8):

You need to be careful using `<loadproperties>` on a manifest: though it appears to work with short values, it fails when the line-length exceeds 70 characters because of the odd way manifest entries wrap.  The resulting values are truncated.

I wrote a `<scriptdef>` that does what you ask, though it's not fully tested yet.

```
<!--
    Loads entries from a manifest file.

    @jar     The jar from where to read
    @file    A manifest file to read
    @prefix  A prefix to prepend
    @section The name of the manifest section to load
-->
<scriptdef name="loadmf" language="javascript" loaderRef="sharedbuild-loaderRef">
    <attribute name="jar" />
    <attribute name="file" />
    <attribute name="prefix" />
    <attribute name="section" />
    <![CDATA[
        var jarname = attributes.get("jar");
        var filename = attributes.get("file");
        if (jarname != null && filename != null) {
            self.fail("Only one of jar or file is required");
        }
        var prefix = attributes.get("prefix");
        if (prefix == null) {
            prefix = "";
        }
        var section = attributes.get("section");

        var manifest;
        if (jarname != null) {
            var jarfile = new java.util.jar.JarFile(new java.io.File(jarname));
            manifest = jarfile.getManifest();
        } else if (filename != null) {
            manifest = new java.util.jar.Manifest(new java.io.FileInputStream(new java.io.File(filename)));
        } else {
            self.fail("One of jar or file is required");
        }

        if (manifest == null) {
            self.log("No manifest in " + jar);
        } else {
            var attributes = (section == null) ? manifest.getMainAttributes() : manifest.getAttributes(section);
            if (attributes != null) {
                var iter = attributes.entrySet().iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    var entry = iter.next();
                    project.setProperty(prefix + entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
    ]]>
</scriptdef>
```

I'm sure the JavaScript can be improved--I'm no expert--but it seems to work well-enough for me (running AntUnit tests to make sure my OSGi manifests are created correctly.)  As an added bonus it loads from either a jar (or ear or war) file or a stand-alone manifest file.

Comment: sure, but line length > 70 chars is calling for trouble and very uncommon

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it's calling for trouble, since it's a standard part of the jar specification.  It's not as uncommon as you think; OSGi, for one, commonly creates very long manifest entries.

Comment: thanks for the hint - didn't think of that, so normally loadproperties works but for special purposes you need to use a scripted solution or own ant task

Comment: Another reason to use the JavaScript is to support multi-line Class-Path entries. It looks like loading it as properties only takes the first line.

Comment: @DavidNouls yes I've used had a issue where I was hitting a Windows classpath length limit, the work around was to create a jar with the Class-Path in the MANIFEST.MF and use that.

Answer (score 2):

To grep the value of a key from a Manifest use loadproperties, here's a macrodef to get you going =

```
<macrodef name="mfgrep">
  <attribute name="jar"/>
  <attribute name="key"/>
  <attribute name="update"/>
    <sequential>
      <loadproperties>
        <zipentry zipfile="@{jar}" name="META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"/>
      </loadproperties>
      <echo>@{key} => ${@{key}}</echo>
      <jar jarfile="@{jar}">
        <manifest>
          <attribute name="@{key}" value="@{update}"/>
        </manifest>
      </jar>
    </sequential>
</macrodef> 

 <!-- Grep a key from Manifest and update its value -->
 <mfgrep 
   jar="/home/gilreb/temp/test.jar"
   key="Manifest-Version"
   update="2.0"
 />
```

optionally you may use nested filterchains within loadproperties

Answer (score 1):

Thanks All,

FYI this is my final code, tested working

This appends a revision number (4th element) to a version without a revision or replaces the revision for a version that already has one.

```
<available file="META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" property="has.manifest" />

<target name="loadBundleVersion" if="has.manifest">
    <!-- load version, if no current build number -->
    <loadproperties srcfile="META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
        <filterchain>
            <linecontainsregexp>
                <regexp pattern="^Bundle-Version: \d*.\d*.\d*\s*$" />
            </linecontainsregexp>
        </filterchain>
    </loadproperties>
</target>

<target name="loadBundleVersionRemoveBuild" unless="Bundle-Version" depends="loadBundleVersion">
    <!-- if version not set here we have a current build number so needs to be stripped -->
    <loadproperties srcfile="META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
        <filterchain>
            <linecontains>
                <contains value="Bundle-Version" />
            </linecontains>
            <tokenfilter>
                <replaceregex pattern=".\d*$" replace="" />
            </tokenfilter>
        </filterchain>
    </loadproperties>
</target>

<target name="loadBundleDetails" depends="loadBundleVersionRemoveBuild">
    <loadproperties srcfile="META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
        <filterchain>
            <linecontains>
                <contains value="Bundle-SymbolicName" />
            </linecontains>
        </filterchain>
    </loadproperties>
</target>

<target name="updateManifestVersion" if="has.manifest" depends="loadBundleDetails">
    <manifest file="META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" mode="update">
        <attribute name="Bundle-Version" value="${Bundle-Version}.${build.number}" />
    </manifest>
</target>
```