# How to read versioncode from manifest.xml in build.xml using ant

Tags: android, ant

I want to rename my apk from myapp-release.apk to myapp-1.0.30.apk. I want to do this in build.xml. I want to read the version in my manifest and then rename the apk.
I am doin this using ant.

thanks,
sneha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question:

```
<path id="android.antlibs">
            <pathelement path="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/anttasks.jar" />
</path>
<taskdef name="xpath" classname="com.android.ant.XPathTask" classpathref="android.antlibs" />
<xpath input="./AndroidManifest.xml" expression="/manifest/@android:versionName" output="manifest.versionName" />
<echo message="versionName = ${manifest.versionName}" />
```

Comment: in my case the jar was in ${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/ant-tasks.jar :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the macrodef from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5318044/130683 and adapt it to your needs, means something like :

```
<macrodef name="mfgrep">
  <attribute name="jar"/>
  <attribute name="key"/>
  <attribute name="keysave"/>
    <sequential>
      <loadproperties>
        <zipentry zipfile="@{jar}" name="META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"/>
      </loadproperties>
      <echo>@{key} => ${@{key}}</echo>
      <property name="@{keysave}" value="${@{key}}"/>
    </sequential>
</macrodef> 

 <!-- Grep a key from Manifest -->
 <mfgrep 
   jar="/home/gilreb/temp/test.jar"
   key="Specification-Version"
   keysave="foobar"
 />
```

afterwards use property ${foobar} for renaming your file :

```
<move file="myapp-release.apk" tofile="myapp-${foobar}.apk"/>
```