# Get an entry of a Manifest file with ant

Tags: ant, manifest, multiline

I am trying to develope an Ant macrodef which gets the values separated by commas of the `Require-Bundle` property in a Manifest file passed as parameter. What I want to obtain is something like this:

`Require-Bundle=org.eclipse.ui,org.eclipse.ui.ide,org.eclipse.ui.views`...

The problem I am facing in my code is that it doesn't take into account if the property has multiple values in multiple lines, here is my code:

```
<macrodef name="getDependencies">
    <attribute name="file" />
    <attribute name="prefix" default="ant-mf." />
    <sequential>
        <loadproperties>
            <file file="@{file}" />
            <filterchain>
                <linecontains>
                    <contains value="Require-Bundle" />
                </linecontains>
                <prefixlines prefix="@{prefix}" />
            </filterchain>
        </loadproperties>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

But this is what I get:

`[echoproperties] ant-mf.Require-Bundle=org.eclipse.ui,`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Chad Nouis I have changed the macrodef approach to scriptdef. I have debugged and adapted the Richard Steele script to fit my needs:

```
<!--
    Loads entries from a manifest file.
    @manifest   A manifest file to read
    @entry      The name of the manifest entry to load (optional)
    @prefix     A prefix to prepend (optional)
-->
<scriptdef name="getDependencies" language="javascript" description="Gets all entries or a specified one of a manifest file">
    <attribute name="manifest" />
    <attribute name="entry" />
    <attribute name="prefix" />
    <![CDATA[
        var filename = attributes.get("manifest");
        var entry = attributes.get("entry");
        if (entry == null) {
            entry = "";
        }
        var prefix = attributes.get("prefix");
        if (prefix == null) {
            prefix = "";
        }

        var manifest;
        if (filename != null) {
            manifest = new java.util.jar.Manifest(new java.io.FileInputStream(new java.io.File(filename)));
        } else {
            self.fail("File is required");
        }

        if (manifest == null) {
            self.log("Problem loading the Manifest");
        } else {
            var attributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();
            if (attributes != null) {
                if (entry != "") {
                    project.setProperty(prefix + entry, attributes.getValue(entry));
                } else {
                    var it = attributes.keySet().iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        var key = it.next();
                        project.setProperty(prefix + key, attributes.getValue(key));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]]>
</scriptdef>
```

Comment: You should close the input stream after the manifest object got instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your Manifest file looks like this:

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.ui.ide,
 org.eclipse.ui.views,
 ...
```

Unfortunately, Java Manifest files aren't quite Java Properties files. Manifest files can have attributes that span multiple lines whereas Property files can't have multi-line values. The `<loadproperties>` task can't handle multi-line attributes.

Instead, you'll need an Ant task that knows about Manifest files. In another question, [Richard Steele provides Ant script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5340557/1078068) that loads a Manifest file from a Jar file. You can adapt the example to get just the `Require-Bundle` attribute.