# Ant task : read and user manifest implementation version

Tags: java, ant, version, manifest

I'm quite new to ant tasks, I've so far managed to call an exec with some args, now I'm trying to read a version from the `META-IF/MANIFEST.MF` file to call an exec with the `Implementation-Version` property of this file as an arg (this is meant to create a versioned setup for my project). 
So far I could only find how to replace properties or how to read from a jar file, but never from a `MANIFEST.MF` file and use the read property as a var for later in the ant task!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can refer the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5313438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [loadfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html) task, with nested [FilterChain](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html)s :

```
<loadfile property="implementation.version" srcFile="MANIFEST.MF">
    <filterchain>
        <!-- following filter tokenize input file and return only
             the lines that match the pattern. Matched string is 
             replaced by an empty string to get only the value of the
             manifest property.
        -->
        <tokenfilter>
            <containsregex pattern="Implementation-Version:[ \t]*" replace="" flags="i"/>
        </tokenfilter>
    </filterchain>
</loadfile>
<!-- now 'implementation.version' contains the rest of the line that was matching the regex -->
<echo>Implementation version is ${implementation.version}</echo>
```